# Matrix type mapping with Doctrine entities

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, relational-database

I have a bit of an issue. i am modeling a DB structure using Doctrine 2 entities and I got stuck with one relation.

What I need to represent in the database is a matrix like table:

```
| |A|B|C|D|
|A|  x
|B|x   x
|C|  x   x
|D|    x
```

What the table shows is what offers are available with other offers (x=true, empty = false).
What I tried to do is a Many to Many relationship with doctrine, hoping that this will generate a mapping table, but Doctrine does not do that.
Here is my entity:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Core\Repository\Main")
 * @ORM\Table(name="offer_availability") 
 */

class OfferAvailability implements JsonSerializable
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var String
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\Offers\OfferAvailability", mappedBy="availableWith", inversedBy="availableWith", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected $availableWith;
```

I know I can create the mapping table entity manually and Use One to Many relations. But what I am wondering if there is a more clever way of approaching this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i have found the issue. Creating mappings in this case only confuses Doctrine. Removing mapping and inversion compleely solved the problem:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\Offers\OfferAvailability", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
protected $availableWith;
```

This generated a mapping table:

```
------------------------------------
|offeravailablity_offeravailability|
------------------------------------
|offeravailability_source          |
|offeravailability_target          |
------------------------------------
```